# jQuery toggle div from select option

Tags: jquery, toggle, html-select, asmselect

I'm in need to toggle divs from a dropdown select option box. I'd like it similar to [asmselect](http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html) for jquery but instead of listing the option tag I'd like it to display a hidden div. Is there anything like this out there? Or anyone know how to set it up? Thanks, Jeff.

**UPDATED**

Basically what I want is the look and interaction of the asmselect link above though toggling divs instead of generating a list. Example code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#theSelect").change(function(){          
        $("#theSelect option:selected").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

            $(theDiv).toggle(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            }),function(){
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
            }
        }); 
    });

});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="selectContainer">
        <select id="theSelect">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="Patient">Patient</option>
            <option value="Physician">Physician</option>
            <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden isPatient">Patient</div>
    <div class="hidden isPhysician">Physician</div>
    <div class="hidden isNurse">Nurse</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with your requirements?  I'm not sure I'm following what you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tYvQ8/

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {          
    var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
    var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

    theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
    theDiv.siblings('[class*=is]').slideUp(function() { $(this).addClass("hidden"); });
});​
```

When the select option changes, you

- Reveal the selected `div` with `slideDown()` and remove its `hidden` class.
- Find the `div`s siblings that have "is" in the class name. (Be easier if the menu wasn't a sibling.)
- Hide the previously displayed siblings with `slideUp()`, which takes a callback to add the `hidden` class after the `slideUp()` is complete

**Here's another (in my opinion, better) way:** http://jsfiddle.net/tYvQ8/1/

Get rid of your `hidden` class, and use jQuery to hide them. Then you don't have to worry about adding and removing the class.

**HTML without hidden class**

```
<body>
    <div class="selectContainer">
        <select id="theSelect">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="Patient">Patient</option>
            <option value="Physician">Physician</option>
            <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="isPatient">Patient</div>
    <div class="isPhysician">Physician</div>
    <div class="isNurse">Nurse</div>
</body>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[class^=is]').hide();

$("#theSelect").change(function(){          
    var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
    var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

    theDiv.slideDown();
    theDiv.siblings('[class^=is]').slideUp();
});​
```

Comment: I'm now looking to add to this to make it like the asmselect plugin so that it will display multiple divs and disable them on the selector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

List options and div tags can be identified and toggled the same way.

$('#div_id').toggle();

So instead of using an element selector to select an option tag like the asmselect plugin you referenced uses, just modify the element selector to select a div tag on the page.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I can't seem to get it working, can you take a look at my code above.

Comment: Actually, this code looks good and I was able to make it work.  What is the error you are seeing?  My only suggestion would have been to change the line that you define theDiv on to be a string instead of an element object.  For example:  

var theDiv = ".is" + value;

This way, you would be calling $(theDiv) like I would have done it.  But as I said, your way worked just fine for me.  Post the error and what browser you are using and perhaps I can offer a different suggestion.

Comment: try changing the value of theDiv and testing on webkit.  My guess is that will fix it.  I would try it for you but I don't have access to a webkit browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use .change() as previously mentioned, but with jquery's .show() and/or .hide() methods:

```
    if($(this).val() == 'selected_option') {
        $('.selector1').show(); //displays element with display:none;        
    } else {
        $('.selector1').hide(); //hides element again
    }
```