# Toggle class from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I try to toggle a class by selecting a option in the dropdown menu, i've tried using a alert() to check if it works but i cant seem to get it to work.

***HTML***:

```
<html>
<body>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">Steinkjer</option>
        <option value="2">Verdal</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

***Javascript:***

```
$('#dropdown option:selected').click(function(){
    var getText = $('#dropdown option').text();
    alert($('.overlay-'+getText));
});
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: ("#dropdown option:selected").text();

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle div from select option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767284/jquery-toggle-div-from-select-option)

Answer (score 4):

`$('#dropdown option:selected')` is not a live object. Your code binds the click handler to the selected option on page load. You should either use event delegation or better listen to `change` event of the `select` element.

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    // Get text content of the selected option
    var getText = $('option:selected', this).text();
    // Get current value of the select element
    // var getValue = this.value;
    console.log(getText);
    console.log($('.overlay-'+getText));
});
```

Comment: When i click the dropdown, and supposed to get the text inside the <option>TEXT</option> tag. I only get in response: [Object object]

Comment: @Bin4ry That's because you are alerting a jQuery object. You should use `console.log` for debugging. Also for logging the text you should log the `getText` variable not that jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

> - Check document.ready is executed
> - Assign the change event
>
> To bind some events to DOM elements, requires a document.ready, to
>   ensure the DOM element is sure created at the time you associate the
>   event.

- A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready.": https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    var getText = $('#dropdown option:selected').html();
    $("#test").removeClass();
    $("#test").toggleClass("overlay-" + getText);
  });



});
```

```css
.overlay-Steinkjer {
  background-color: red;
}
.overlay-Verdal {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Steinkjer</option>
    <option value="2">Verdal</option>
  </select>

  <p id="test">test paragraph</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would i make it so it toggles the class i get, this is what i tried:

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    var getText = $('#dropdown option:selected').html();
    $('.overlay-'+getText).toggle();
  });
});

Comment: $("#objID").toggleClass("classname"); let me make a change to show you

Comment: well this didnt work: $('#dropdown').toggleClass('.overlay-'+getText);

Comment: you need to remove the "." from your class name. the . is only used in CSS or JQUERY selectors to mean THIS is a class:  "$(".green") <-- it looks for elements with "green" class, not ".green" the . means class, the # ID.... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp